# C#, EPPLUS - How Can I ensure the scroll bar on every sheet in the excel is always on Top

Tags: c#, epplus

I am able to Dynamically create an excel, carry out appropriate manipulations and save the same using EPPLUS library. The only issue is, when I Open the saved excel, on every sheet I observe scroll bar in the middle or dragged to the bottom. How can I ensure the scroll bar is always on top (so that the first row is always visible) on all sheets?

Comment: Is other excel (which are not created by EPPLUS) is showing same behavior ?

Comment: Nope...On other excels, as long as you have ensured the scroll bar is on the top in every sheet and then saved, it will open as is.

Comment: Do you have any code that would allow us to reproduce this? The default active cell is `A1` so the first row should always be visible when you open. Are you setting the active cell by accident or are you using an existing Excel to generate? You can reset/change the active cell manually but I can't tell if that would be the appropriate solution.